# Function set default image when image not present

Tags: php, functions

I am using this code for search results display:

```
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' );
    $my_image = ( $image[0] != '' ) ? ' <img alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" class="tagim" src="' . $image[0] . '"/>' : '';
```

This works fine but I am getting `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: output` if the post does not have a featured image.

In this case what would be the best way to point to a default placeholder image for the `"src"` in variable `$my_image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to put the `<img/>` tag and all the necessary content for the default image after the final colon in the following line:

```
$my_image = ( $image[0] != '' ) ? ' <img alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" class="tagim" src="' . $image[0] . '"/>' : '';
```

What that line does is say that **if** the `$image[0]` variable is **not equal** to blank (`$image[0] != ''`), then use the following, and it then supplies the image tag, the `title`, the `alt` and `src`.  Then the segment after the colon is basically the **else**.  So if **NOT BLANK** do this **ELSE** do this.  What you've got as an else is basically nothing.

So try this, where we're adding something to the ELSE portion:

```
$my_image = ( $image[0] != '' ) ? ' <img alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" class="tagim" src="' . $image[0] . '"/>' : ' <img alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" class="tagim" src="theurlforyourdefaultimage.com/imagename.png"/>';
```

You'll need to provide the URL to your default image.  Not sure if it's in a folder in your theme, or something you've uploaded, but for the time being you can just use the full URL to test.

I guess also determine if you still want the same `alt` and `title` even if there's a default instead of a featured image or if you want them to also be something generic.